# C++ with .NET: updating chart via timer

Tags: winforms, timer, charts, c++-cli

I have some C++ code that performs calculations and I would like to visualize it.
I'm using windows forms (.NET).
The idea is to perform calculations in C++ and to include .h with chart.
As I need fast update, I use timer.  As my data is in C++ I should use some tricks to draw it from .h.  I was advised to use BeginInvoke() method, here's my proto code from header:

```
System::Void ActionD ()
{ 
    for (pts = 0; pts < arrlength; pts++) {
        chart1->series1->Points->AddXY(test_array_x[pts], test_array_y[pts]);
    } 
}   
private:
System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {    
     MethodInvoker^ mi = gcnew MethodInvoker(this,&ActionD);
     chart1->Invoke(mi);
     //check if timer works:
     Beep(300,500); 
}
```

I have some errors: "...MethodInvoker: a delegate constructor expects 1 argument"
Question is if the general concept of code correct and how can I fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

The C++/CLI compiler in older versions of VS don't produce a very good diagnostic for bad delegate constructor calls.  The issue is with &ActionD, it needs to be a fully qualified method name, like this:

```
 MethodInvoker^ mi = gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &Form1::ActionD);
```

Replace "Form1" with the name of your form class if necessary.

And no, the general concept is not correct.  You are using a regular Winforms timer, there's no need at all to use BeginInvoke since the code already runs on the main thread.  Nor would you be ahead at all by using an asynchronous timer class, it doesn't make the code any faster.

You make your chart fast by filtering the data, only keeping the Points in the series that you actually need to get an accurate chart drawn.  Which doesn't take a lot of points, a few hundred up to a thousand is more than enough.  Monitors don't have a lot of pixels so using multiple thousands just keeps the Chart control busy for no benefit.  Doing that filtering in a worker thread is the way to get ahead.

Comment: Thank you. There is about 50 dots to plot, so nothing to speed up. If I'm using just chart1->series1->Points->addxy() in timer, I have an error that series1 is not a member of Chart.Maybe we should use some pointer here?

Comment: C++/CLI isn't different from C++, using proper capitalization matters.  .NET member names use camel-casing, it is Series1 and AddXY.  Do let IntelliSense help you out with getting that right.

Comment: Sorry, I use phone to post here so I didn't used capital letters.I copied names exactly from code that designer created for me.Should be something else.

Comment: Sigh.  What kind of phone can run a C++/CLI compiler?  You cannot possibly check if the help you get solves your problem.  You are wasting my time :(

Comment: I never said that I'm using phone to compile.I use VS 2010 Express.BTW, there is a compiler called GCCDroid that can run C++ on Android.

Comment: Is it possible to say something on this or should I go smoke all the manuals?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a little bit similar topic:
[How can I update data in a chart in execution time (in C++ builder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840251/how-can-i-update-data-in-a-chart-in-execution-time-in-c-builder?rq=1)

So I'm doing this inside my timer:

System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series^ seriezz1 = chart1->Series[0];
seriezz1->Points->AddXY(test_array_x[pts], test_array_y[pts]);

It compiles, but crashes at start :(